# Assignment of values in a array index

Tags: java, arrays

Please look at the below code snippet and let me know how the out comes out as 1 2 .

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
System.out.println( a [ (a = b)[3] ] );
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Actual answer 1
2

Thanks

Comment: What was your intension? Are you sure that you want to assign b to a (a=b), or did you want to compare anything (==)?

Comment: Whatever his intention is, this is an interesting result.

Comment: This is not production code :), Its more learning code ... I am just trying to wrap my head around the order of execution and I agree it look crap :)

Comment: @enobayram - This is the result I would expect. He first assignes b to a, then prints the value of index 3 and finally the value of index 0.

Comment: @Sudarshan just look at the resulting bytecode

Comment: You claim the result is `1 2`. The actual result is that everyone reading the code will be thinking `wtf`. This is a much more important aspect of the code above. Please, for the love of everyone ever re-reading your code (including yourself), never ever write code like that.

Comment: @mrab Well, he prints the value in a at the index that is the value in b at the index of 3. The result of this changes depending on when (a=b) is executed. The interesting part is that I had never stopped to think when variables are read and written to in java.

Comment: Well, I would say that the result will be `2 2` if I didn't test it. Interesting question +1 :)

Comment: For everyone blasting the code ... This is not production code :), Its more learning code ...  Trust me :P

Comment: @Sudarshan If you look at the spec it might also help you understand the `(a=b)[3]` section. Check out [Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) and [Parenthesized Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5). They state that `The type of the assignment expression is the type of the variable after capture conversion.` and `A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type is the type of the contained expression and whose value at run-time is the value of the contained expression.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to explain:

`a [ (a = b)[3] ]` will be executed in the following order:

1. `a [...]` - the array `a` will be read and the reference is stored for that
2. `(a = b)` - the variable `a` is set to reference array `b`
3. `(a=b)[3]` - the 4th element of array `b` is read (because of step 2) , the value is `0`
4. `a [ (a = b)[3] ]` - this is now equal to `a[0]` (because of steps 1 and 3), the value is `1`

`a[0]` now yields `2` since `a` references array `b` (because of step 2) and the first element in that array is `2`.

Answer (score 7):

Seriously, what is the purpose of this? Why would you ever wanna do something that makes the code so unreadable. What would you expect the outcome to be?

The result of `System.out.println( a [ (a = b)[3] ] );` has to do with the order in which things are pushed to the evaluation stack ... e.g.

1. reference to a
2. change reference stored in a to that stored in b
3. evaluated b[3] => 0
4. print index 0 of the array to which reference was pushed in 1.), i.e. the original a

so it prints the element at 0 of the original `a` array

`System.out.println(a[0]);` is then simply `b[0]`

Comment: b[3] is 0 (fourth element), that's why 1 is printed, it's a[0]. However, it's really strange that the original a is still evaluated in step 4, don't know if it's part of the specs...

Comment: Yup thanks :), look at my above comment to know why i wrote such a question in the first place :)

Comment: no it is not strange at all, if you read the bytecode you'll see in which order things are pushed and popped from the stack. Anyways, it just server him right to get the unexpected result when doing stupid things such as `a[ (a=b)[3] ]`

Comment: To me this looks more like an exercise question on a textbook, with the intent of testing readers on a concept. I don't think the person asking the question would ever use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

First two lines initialize your arrays. First sysout assigns b to a then prints a[3], ie. your a is now having values {2,3,1,0}. Second sysout prints a[0].